# Quantum $n$-body problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, many-body, three-body-problem

Is the [quantum $n$-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-body_problem) as difficult as the [classical $n$-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem)?

Or quantum mechanics allows to get a simpler exact solution?

Suppose there are 3 particles with uniform potential field. Can their wave functions be found exactly?

Comment: Related classical problem: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1235/2451

Comment: Is there _anything_ exact in QM? My guess is no.

Comment: Definitely, the quantum state in most problems can be found exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quantum $n$-body problem is considerably simpler than the classical $n$-body problem, since the problems with collisions disappear. Rigorous existence results are much stronger. See, e.g., the book [''Scattering theory of classical and quantum N-particle systems''](http://books.google.at/books?hl=en&lr=&id=NYMIcCR8qWgC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Derezinski&ots=bUp2vVdtnE&sig=HueoGVGHx0blaver5jLNfQb-Mvc) by Derezinski and Gérard.

But explicit solutions are about as rare in the quantum case as in the classical case.