# Three-body problem in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, three-body-problem

Usually a two-body nuclear problem is exactly solvable through quantum mechanics e.g. the deuteron nucleus having two particles a neutron and proton. As one goes over to three particle systems, say a triton or a neutron described as composed of three quarks, the equations get coupled. Is there a simple way out to get to calculate the ground state of three particle systems?

Comment: i am asking the above so that i can update myself by the answers  about solution of three particle bound state problems which we used to attempt in 1970's through variational approaches.

Comment: Probably related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37938/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74332

Comment: Google Fadeev equation.