# Why can't we humans solve the three-body-problem? and why can computers solve it?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, chaos-theory, three-body-problem

Why is it that we humans can't solve the three-body-problem? (calculate the positions of the 3 bodies in a dynamical system)

And why can computers do it?

My thoughts:

Computers do it in way smaller steps then us humans, and if we tried to replicate what the computer does, it would take ages.

Comment: anything that computers do is done because a human has written out how to solve the problem in a bunch of tiny steps.  The computer merely steps through those steps.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1235/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There has been recent discovery of new classes of solutions: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2013/03/physicists-discover-whopping-13-new-solutions-three-body-problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computers can't.

You're right that they perform numerical integration way faster than we can, but, slower or faster, it's believed that neither people nor computers can solve the three-body problem. At least not in the sense of finding a [closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_solution), analytical solution.

These small-step calculations computers do produce only approximations to the solutions.

It's worth pointing out again, though, that the three-body problem is *expected* to be non-integrable. [There's no proof yet](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Three_body_problem#Non-integrability).